# Does the PDF Box has the issue text read from PDF document converts from upper to lower

Tags: text, pdfbox, uppercase

I had seen in the PDFbox forums, some upper case letters are read in lower case. Please check the following thread.

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/201303.mbox/%3C8BED247A-E6CD-4895-BF9B-85BB28C2C1E2@fileaffairs.de%3E

It's an old thread. But, I am wondering, whether this problem exists with PDFBox 2.x. We are using the PDF Box version 2.0.13.

Let us know, if any one come across this issue with PDFBox 2.x.

- CM

Comment: Yes the problem still exists in PDFBox 2.0.*.

Comment: is there any work around for this issue ?

Comment: No, this is not even a bug, rather a lack of supporting an exotic PDF feature, i.e. to get the replacement text in the marked content. It is possible that it was discussed in some issue or some SO question, but no solution in PDFBox.